# How to validate the paypal account the payer is trying to use before the payment is accepted?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I set up a payment system using Paypal + IPN. Everything works fine but now I wonder how can I validate, for example, the payer's email before the payment is complete?

More specifically, I want to do this: every user can use any account when they pay the first time, but when the same customer makes another payment, I want to force him/her to use the very same Paypal email...

When Paypal notifies me (to my IPN listener) about the payment, the payment is already "Complete" so how can I achieve that and reject the payment if it does not come from the email I expect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no functionality to validate payer's email. But you can try this option: perform refund if payer used inappropriate email.

Comment: Thanks, I think that is what I will do. :)